# I keep getting the error code 89 on colaboratory

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, error-code

When I ran the code on the image shown it shows the error code 89. I generated a new consumer key, consumer secret,  access token, and access token secret and it still does not work the error code 89 still shows. What should I do?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujtsE.jpg

Answer (score 0):

The error shown suggests your OAuth API token for accessing twitter has expired. You'll need to obtain a new one.

Comment: do I get the OAuth API token from twitter or Google OAuth 2.

Comment: See here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/oauth-1-0a/obtaining-user-access-tokens